# OkHttp 3 Interceptor list

Tags: android, retrofit, okhttp

i'm trying to make my tests work with `Retrofit2` / `Okhttp` 3 and wrote an Interceptor that works like [this](https://github.com/square/retrofit/blob/763fe1639e3348480214873323caacd00cbd7fa6/retrofit/src/test/java/retrofit/MockClient.java) one:

Unfortunately the `Deque<>` of events is always empty, although the method adding the items to the queue is called before `intercept()`.

Do you have any other ideas how to achieve the same effect when testing my code? i used robolectric with a synchronous executor.
Before i overrode `retrofit.client.Client`s `execute()` and it worked fine.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

For an alternative, you may set up a ThreadPoolExecutor instance directly using execution strategy, or might block in the case of synchronous execution.

Comment: The problem is that i want to serve my custom responses and they are not inside the queue. So I need another strategy to create an Interceptor / Client / Dispatcher.